# nativeQuery in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA.

I am trying to create a nativequery with 3 joins on 3 tables.

I have written a nativequery which is something like the below:

```
Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery("select p.value,m.value,t.value,t.value from ping as p,ming as m,ting as t where p.id=m.vid and m.id=t.vid");

List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
```

I have 3 tables ping,ming,ting in my database.

I have got syntax error during execution.

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ping as p,ming as m ,ting as t';
```

Would be helpful if some one can point me the error and What would be the better solution to join different tables over nativequery in JPA.

EDIT:I have successfully run the above query on mysql.

Comment: Did you try running that query with some other tool (e.g. commandline client, phpMyAdmin or whatever tool for MySQL you are using)?

Comment: run this `select p.value,m.value,t.value,t.value from ping as p,ming as m,ting as t where p.id=m.vid and m.id=t.vid` in mysql and check if it is correct or not

Comment: I am able to run the above query successfully in mysql prompt

Comment: @starkk92 remove one t.value and try.If that does not work then try `select p.value,m.value as value1,t.value as value2 from ping as p
inner join ming as m on  p.id=m.vid 
inner join ting as t on m.id=t.vid ` and let me know if you are successful or not

Comment: I have already tried this and its working fine on prompt,not in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how alias on the column is causing the problem.

I have tried running the program with out alias on the columns and everything is fine.

Found the similar question here.
[hibernate native SQL query error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055790/hibernate-native-sql-query-error)

Answer (score 0):

'ping as p,ming as m ,ting as t'

Try to put dot instead coma.

Maybe your syntax is incorrect

Comment: _doc_? Did you mean _dot_?

Comment: dot, yes. Sorry for my bad english :(